# Evaluate indefinite integral $\int \frac{1}{\sin x + \sec x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate
$$\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{\sin x + \sec x}$$
My work is to substitute $\sin x = u$.
Then $\sec x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)}}$
and $dx = \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)}}$
and I got this formula

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{du}{1+ u\sqrt{(1-u^2)}} $$

But I could not evaluate the previous integral.

Comment: Use the [tangent half-angle substitution (a.k.a. The Weierstrass Substitution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's try to find the integral we get with the famous tangent half-angle substitution:
$$\int\frac{2(1-t^2)}{t^4 - 2t^3 + 2t^2 + 2t + 1}\,dt.$$
The denominator is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, but...
$$t^4 - 2t^3 + 2t^2 + 2t + 1=
\left(t^2 + (-1 - \sqrt{3})t + (2 + \sqrt{3})\right)
\left(t^2 + (-1 + \sqrt{3})t + (2 - \sqrt{3})\right)$$
Partial fraction decomposition of the integrand gives
$$\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{t+1}{t^2 + (-1 + \sqrt{3})t + (2 - \sqrt{3})}
-\frac{t+1}{t^2 + (-1 - \sqrt{3})t + (2 + \sqrt{3})}\right)
$$
Now it's a relatively standard (though extremely tedious) exercise to evaluate the indefinite integral
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\frac{t^2 + (-1 + \sqrt{3})t + (2 - \sqrt{3})}{t^2 + (-1 - \sqrt{3})t + (2 + \sqrt{3})}+\arctan(1+(1+\sqrt{3})t)+\arctan(1+(1-\sqrt{3})t)$$
Pedantic profs may urge you to add an integration constant, though that's only relevant for general solutions of differential equations.

Answer (score 3):

your integrand is $$\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$
and then $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: Yes it is , but i could not evaluate it also in this form

Comment: The only way to solve it will be with tangent half-angle substitution, I think, as Dr Graubner suggested.

Comment: Wolfram has a rather nasty answer for this

Comment: Yeah, that does look promising:
$$\int\frac{2(1-t^2)}{t^4 - 2t^3 + 2t^2 + 2t + 1}\,dt.$$
The denominator is irreducible (over the rationals).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac\pi4 -\frac t2$ to integrate
\begin{align}
 \displaystyle\int \frac{1}{\sin x + \sec x}dx
=& \>\sqrt2 \int \frac{\cos\frac t2+ \sin\frac t2 }{\cos t +2}dt\\
=& \>\sqrt2\int \frac{d (\sin\frac t2) }{\frac32 -\sin^2 \frac t2}
-\sqrt2\int \frac{d (\cos\frac t2) }{\cos^2 \frac t2+\frac12}\\
= &\frac2{\sqrt3} \tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{\frac23}\sin\frac t2)-2\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2\cos\frac t2)+C
\end{align}

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify how you got the first step?

Comment: @aarbee - $\cos(\frac\pi4 -\frac t2)=\frac1{\sqrt2}(\cos\frac t2+ \sin\frac t2 )$